# Best way to update prices using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

First of I'm writing this post on my phone while on the road. Sorry for lack of info just trying to get a head start for when I get home.

I have 2 csv files, both of which contain a different amount of columns and a different amount of records. The first file has about 150k records and the second has about 1.2mil records. The first file the first column has values that are both in a column in the second file and values that are not in the second file. What i intend to do is to check if the value in column one of the first file is in the first column of the second file.  If so check if the first files second column is less than our greater than a value of a different column in the second file where the first columns match. If so update the first files second column to the new value.

*Side note* I don't need the fastest or most efficient way I just need a working solution for now. Iwill optimize later. Code will be ran once a month to update csv file.

Currently I am attempting to accomplish this using pandas and loading each file into a dataframe. I am struggling to make this work.  If this is the best way could you help me do this? Once I figure out how to do this I can figure out the rest I'm just stuck.

What I thought of before I posted this question that I might try to make a third dataframe containing the columns that hold material values and DCost values where Item column and Material columns match.  The looping through the dataframe and if value from Item and Material column match updat cost column in csv file

I didn't know if uploading the csv files to a database and running queries to accomplish this would be easier?

Would converting the dataframes to dicts work with this much data?

**File 1**

```
+--------+-------+--------+
|  Item  | Cost  | Price  |
+--------+-------+--------+
| Labor  |     0 | 100.00 |
| 785342 | 12.54 |  24.76 |
| 620388 | 15.78 |  36.99 |
+--------+-------+--------+
```

**File 2**

```
+----------+--------+-----------+
| Material | DCost  | List Cost |
+----------+--------+-----------+
| 10C0024  |    .24 |      1.56 |
| 785342   |  12.54 |     23.76 |
| 620388   |  16.99 |     36.99 |
| 2020101  | 100.76 |    267.78 |
+----------+--------+-----------+
```

**Intended result to export to csv.**

```
+--------+-------+--------+
| Labor  | Cost  | Price  |
+--------+-------+--------+
| Labor  |     0 | 100.00 |
| 785342 | 12.54 |  23.76 |
| 620388 | 16.99 |  36.99 |
+--------+-------+--------+
```

Comment: Could you add a couple more examples/outputs? It's a little unclear as to why `18C808` seems to contain the additional data for calculating new cost. It may also help to include some dummy `dataframes` with intended outputs.

Comment: @PacketLoss I edited the question